# knockoutjs validation, immediately validate

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am adding a viewmodel to an observableArray, then binding it to a 'each' binding in the html.

The current knockout validation only shows the error if the user typed in something then emptied the textbox.However i want the errors to show, immediatly after the viewmodel is added to my observable array.,

Answer (score 0):

```
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false, // this must NOT be true.
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
}, true);
```

Found the answer.